# how to use Oracle integrated data mining functions to detect outliers present in the data set

Tags: oracle, plsql, data-mining

I have installed oracle10g enterprise edition on my computer. I want to find the outliers from the dataset, how this can be achieved using the dbms_data_mining_transform package. I knew simple statistical methods. But i have to do within the Database details. I dont want to fetch large dataset outside the database.

Please somebody help me in this. Or suggest something that i can do in oracle to find outliers.

Comment: Please post the definition of your tables, some sample data and the expected result. And make sure code and examples are formatted properly

Answer (score 0):

```
begin
  dbms_data_mining.create_model(
   'TEST1', 'CLUSTERING', 'DATATAB_TO_MINE', null);
end;
/
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/datamine.111/b28131/models_building.htm#BCGDADID